# autocomplete taxonomy field depend on another taxonomy field

Tags: taxonomy-terms

There is a content type Animal in which two taxonomy field are used  say Animal Type and Breeds . Breeds taxonomy is autocomplete taxonomy field . so What i want Breeds taxonomy field  depend on Animal type taxonomy field. i.e, when cats are select from animal type field then breeds taxonomy show only cats type breeds .How can this acheive ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is a drupal site on development state.

If it is possible to you, I recommend you to create just one taxonomy vocabulary, where Animal type are parent terms of Breeds terms as a tree:

Cat

- Curl
- Bengal

Dog

- Afghan
- Akita

Then you can use [Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) or [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select), where you can allow users to select a parent term first and then childs.

Hope this help, if you need help with views filters or things like that I can help you :)

Comment: yes , your approach is right but i want it to be done by programatically